# Pull to refresh in Phonegap

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova

I'm trying to use this widget (https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) in a phonegap project, but it uses a List view activity and I'm not wholly sure how to place the Droidgap activity and the TextView within this so it will work.

Any pointers on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know whats there in the pull refresh sample .

But if i would be using any such code which have ListActivity whose functionality i need.
And in my app it is to be ListView only embedded within any other view.
And i can customize it as i need and can place any other view element along with the listview.

What you should do first is modify the sample you downloaded to get the idea.

Change the ListActivity into a Activity class.
Make a layout xml file and embed your listview class within it
like for your case

```
<LinearLayout>
    <com.markupartist.android.widget.PullToRefreshListView 
     all other attributes here
     />

    <embed anything here also> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Now withing onCreate of your class

get the reference of this view and call all the respective methods which are called in ListActivity on self reference call the list view reference.

You will be able to work it out.

Sure check the exact constructor of view class. it can be tricky to use.

Hope it helps

Comment: Not wholley sure how to implement this but I'll give it a poke :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement pull to refresh in JS or use an existing solution like [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

Comment: Hi, ye I'd looked at this, it just wasn't as nice as native :|

Comment: iScroll 4 causes flickering in the page, would not use it

Answer (score 0):

This wont work with phonegap. Remember that the main view of phonegap apps is the webkit browser and this cannot be combined with something anything else.
You have to write this plugin using html+css+javascript inside your app.

Comment: Worked fine on IOS. Couldnt quite work it out in Android (that and I ran out of time)